# foreach fetch_object PHP

Tags: php, drupal, foreach

I have to travel a table and display the result in JSON format. When I do that, it just shows me the first line of the table, then I want it to me all the lines. thank you!

```
function mesum_web_service_expositions (){

  $result = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT * FROM {content_type_exposition} "));

  echo json_encode($result);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: is it a drupal function?

Comment: Either change to a function that fetches all rows or do a normal while($row = db_fetch_object(...

Comment: [Why did not drupal include a 'db_fetch_all' function?](https://www.drupal.org/node/965090)

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: i'm using version 6 of drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call each row in a loop and handle accordingly

db_fetch_object will only select one row

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {content_type_exposition}";

while ($row = db_fetch_object(db_query($sql))) {
    //handle $row
}
```

If you want to return an array of all the results using this method you can add each $row to an array:

```
$obj = db_query($sql);

$result = array();
while ($row = db_fetch_object($obj)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}

var_dump(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the data returned, before you encode it?  Run a var_dump or print_r on $result for example and share it here.  We need to discern between data issues, and issues with json_encode function first.

Comment: here is a look of data before encode it. it still returns just the first line

Comment: It could be your SQL query. It doesn't finish in `LIMIT 1;` does it?

Comment: There's a missing parenthesis. It should be: `while ($row = db_fetch_object($obj)) {`

Answer (score 0):

here is a look of data before encode it. it still returns just the first line!
                                                              stdClass Object ( [vid] => 60886

```
[nid] => 51789 [field_exposition_thumbnail_nid] => 51788 [field_exposition_place_value] => [field_exposition_without_walls_value] => 0 [field_exposition_commissioner_value] =>
Guillaume Faroult, conservateur au département des Peintures

[field_exposition_acknowledge_value] => Avec le soutien de la TERRA FOUNDATION FOR AMERICAN ART Cette exposition-dossier est rendue possible grâce au généreux soutien du Crystal Bridges Museum of American Art, du High Museum of Art, Atlanta, et de la Terra Foundation for American Art. Les programmes de l’Auditorium sont soutenus par les American Friends of the Louvre et le Mark Pigott Lecture and Research Fund. [field_exposition_fup_changed_value] => [field_exposition_fup_created_value] => ) 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@iswinky, here is what i'm getting when i use your solution:

"SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From {content_type_exposition}""SELECT * From